# jQuery for loop results in unexpected results

Tags: wordpress

I am building beaver builder module and my js gives error which I never got. I am running a for loop to run my code 2 times only, but as I am using my module 3 times on the same page then it loads my jquery loop 3 * 2 times = 6 which I don't want at all .... :(

Can any one guide me how to restrict my code to or my loop run only once not thrice ??? Here is my whole jquery code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            var attachFun = function(){
                if(jQuery('.masonaryOuter_v' +i+'').length){
                    var $container = jQuery('.masonaryOuter_v'+i+'');
                    $container.isotope({
                        filter: '*',
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(jQuery('#filterlist_v'+i+' a').length){
                    jQuery('#filterlist_v'+i+' a').click(function(){
                        jQuery('#filterlist_v'+i+' .current').removeClass('current');
                        jQuery(this).addClass('current');

                        var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
                        $container.isotope({
                            filter: selector,
                            animationOptions: {
                                duration: 750,
                                easing: 'linear',
                                queue: false
                            }
                         });
                         return false;
                    }); 
                }
            }

        }
```

Any one to guide me please as I never done this type of work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting a global variable to determine if the code has already run?

```
   if (window.alreadyrun == null) {
       for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
           var attachFun = function() {
               if (jQuery('.masonaryOuter_v' + i + '').length) {
                   var $container = jQuery('.masonaryOuter_v' + i + '');
                   $container.isotope({
                       filter: '*',
                       animationOptions: {
                           duration: 750,
                           easing: 'linear',
                           queue: false
                       }
                   });
               }

               if (jQuery('#filterlist_v' + i + ' a').length) {
                   jQuery('#filterlist_v' + i + ' a').click(function() {
                       jQuery('#filterlist_v' + i + ' .current').removeClass('current');
                       jQuery(this).addClass('current');

                       var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
                       $container.isotope({
                           filter: selector,
                           animationOptions: {
                               duration: 750,
                               easing: 'linear',
                               queue: false
                           }
                       });
                       return false;
                   });
               }
           }

       }
       window.alreadyrun = 1;
   }
```